# Unable to start Redis with modified config (/var => /home/redis)

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, redis

I'm facing an issue when trying to start Redis 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with a modified configuration. Changes in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` are as follow:

```
#logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
logfile /home/redis/logs/redis-server.log
...
#dir /var/lib/redis
dir /home/redis/data
```

Here's the output from `journalctl -xe`:

```
run-parts[5853]: run-parts: executing /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d/00_exampl
redis-server[5857]: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
redis-server[5857]: Reading the configuration file, at line 163
redis-server[5857]: >>> 'logfile /home/redis/logs/redis-server.log'
redis-server[5857]: Can't open the log file: Permission denied
systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

As you can see, start-up seems unable to do anything under `/home/redis` directory whereas it is owned by the `redis` user and group (`chown -R redis:redis /home/redis` applied).

**Footnotes**

- This configuration used to work nicely on Debian Wheezy/Jessie and Ubuntu 14.04
- Redis starts properly with the default configuration
- `touch` and `chmod` the logfile does not fix
- Also tested with Redis 4 (via Chris Lea ppa)

Comment: This can be `selinux`. Check if `selinux` is disabled. Run the following: `selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled`

Comment: And make sure that you have +x permission on /home (not on /home/redis) otherwise listing of /home will be prohibited for user "redis". +x should be on all folders above your target dir...

Comment: `selinux` is not installed. Is it a prerequisite to have Redis starts when `dir` and `logfile` are modified in the configuration? In this case, it should definitely be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by @h0x91B in the comments, you could enable `selinux` and see if it works.

That said, if you don't want to use `selinux`, here's a workaround:

1. edit Redis `systemd` service file `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service`, set `ProtectHome=no` and add `ReadWriteDirectories=-/home/redis`
2. reload systemd with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. start Redis `sudo service redis-server start`

**References**

- http://damiengustave.fr/de-la-securite-de-systemd
- https://serverfault.com/a/801913/338505

Comment: You'd better use `ProtectHome=tmpfs`, so that `/home/` is protected. Good answer though.